# fine-tuning a CNN from a lower fc layer

Tags: computer-vision, neural-network, convolution, deep-learning, caffe

I've noticed that most fine-tuning of CNN over new dataset is done only on the "last" fully connected (fc) layer.

I'm interested in fine-tuning from the "first" fully connected layer: that is, I want to use mid-level features from convolution and pooling layers as they are, (supposing it's trained on ImageNet) but then fit all fc layers to my new dataset.

Theoretically and in practice, what is the supposed effect of this? Is it likely to learn a more proper set of parameters for my new dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically, the deeper you fine-tune, the better your model fits your data. So, if you could fine-tune the whole model - the better.

So, what's the catch, you must be asking, why don't everyone fine-tune the whole model?
First, fine-tuning the whole model involves lots and lots of parameters, in order to train properly millions of parameters without the risk of overfitting, you must have a LOT of new training examples. In most cases, when fine-tuning you only have a very few annotated samples for the new task and therefore you are unable to afford fine-tuning of the whole model.
Second, fine-tuning the whole model takes much longer than training just the top fc layer. Thus, if you have little time and budget you only fine-tune the top fc layer.

In your case, if you have enough samples you may fine-tune the top two fc layers. From my experience it is better to fine tune the top layer first and then fine-tune the top two together after some iterations are done on the top layer alone.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was wondering. I have almost 1.5M images with 100 classes, which I assume are not a trivial amount. Would this be many enough to train 2~3 fc layers and still avoid overfitting?

Comment: @CosmicRabbitMediaInc looks like enough to train the whole net. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of FC layers in a ConvNet is only to perform classification for your problem. You could just use the final flattened output from your last Conv/Pooling layer as engineered features and put it in another machine learning model and it would have the same effect.

This implies that the parameters learned by FC layers in most cases are very problem specific (depends on the data) and, in most cases not transferable.

So whenever people fine tune on a pre-trained model they almost always dump the FC layers on the top.

Now you can go 2 ways from here.

1. Use the final flattened output from the last Conv/Pooling layer as extracted features for your problem and train a ML model on it. This method is commonly used if your data set is small or not similar to the pre-trained model.
2. Get the extracted features using the above method and then use them to train a FC neural network. Once you achieved a decent accuracy stack it on top of last conv/pooling layer of the pre-trained model (dont forget to remove the orignal FC layers). Now freeze(parameters are made constant and dont change on training) most of the pre-trained model and only allow the last few conv layers to be trained. Now train the entire network to train with a very small learning rate.

The whole point of freezing most of the model is that we assume that the model already knows basic stuff like edge detection and color from the earlier conv layers. Now we fine tune the last few layers for the our problem. We chose a small learning rate so that we don't end up messing up what the model has already learned.

The reason we train the FC layers before we fit them on to the pre-trained model is just to save training time and more importantly to ensure that we don't make to much changes to the Conv layers and end up over fitting.